# Spring Microservices Cannot Connect Via Eureka When Inside Docker Container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka

So I have been trying to fix this problem, and 4 days later I still haven't been able to find a solution. I have built an API Gateway using Spring Boot which acts as a Eureka Server via Zuul, and I have a microservice which acts as a Eureka Client. When I run it locally within Intellij, everything works perfect and they discover and connect to eachother. When they are in a container however, I get the following exception:

> 2022-05-16 12:42:49.087  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0]
> c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed
> with m essage: java.net.UnknownHostException: http 2022-05-16
> 12:42:49.088  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0]
> com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    :
> DiscoveryClient_USER/8322e6fdb2 35:user:8082 - registration failed
> Cannot execute request on any known server
>
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot
> execute request on any known server
> at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112
> ) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56
> ) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:5
> 9) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
> ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56
> ) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:850)
> ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:121)
> [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.17]
> at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:101)
> [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar!/:1.9.1 7]
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> [na:1.8.0_332]
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_332]
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> [na:1.8.0_332]
> at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> [na:1.
> 8.0_332]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_332]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_332]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_332]

**My Eureka Server looks like this:**

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  kwettergateway-docker:
    image: user/kwettergateway
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
  userservice-docker:
    image: user/userservice
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    links:
      - kwettergateway-docker
```

Application.properties:

```
server.port=8761

#Gateway properties
spring.application.name=gateway
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty=0
zuul.prefix=/api
zuul.routes.user.path=/user/**
zuul.routes.user.url=http://localhost:8082/
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/kwettergateway-docker.jar kwettergateway-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/kwettergateway-docker.jar"]
```

**My Eureka Client looks like this:**

Application.properties:

```
server.port=8082

#Gateway properties
spring.application.name=user
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Comment: It doesn't run on localhost, it runs in a container. Use the name of the container **instead** of localhost as the host (that is assuming they are running in the same network).

Comment: Assuming the problem is that you would like it to work _both_ when you run from IntelliJ and from the docker-compose, you will need to use different url depending on the environment you are running in. 

You could use a different properties files, e.g `application-local.properties` when running it from IntelliJ. This should only contain the line `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/` and use `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://kwettergateway-docker:8761/eureka/` in the  `application.properties` as default config as @M.Deinum suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to run your application using Docker, so in your application.properties file you should replace localhost to image name. Also, what need to mention, that you should mark you Eureka server with `@EnableEurekaServer`.
If you want to have a look on it, visit - https://github.com/zhurasique/easycar

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the docker host instead of localhost. So it's working now with the following code:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://host.docker.internal:8761/eureka/
```